# how to create a `d.ts` file to import an external npm lib that is not a module

Tags: javascript, typescript, rollupjs

I want to use an npm lib that is not written as a module

`npm install "js-marker-clusterer" --save`

This installs a JS file that I want:

**./node_modules/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js**

```
// this is the Class I want to export/import
function MarkerClusterer(map, opt_markers, opt_options) {
  // ...
}
```

I want to extend and use this Class in my TS file. According to the TS docs, I can declare a `shorthand ambient module` to do this, but I am not sure where to put the different files.

> Shorthand ambient modules
>
> If you don’t want to take the time to write out declarations before
>   using a new module, you can use a shorthand declaration to get started
>   quickly.
>
> *declarations.d.ts*  (where do I put this file?)
>
> ```
> /// <reference path="node.d.ts"/>
> declare module "hot-new-module";
> ```
>
> All imports from a shorthand module will have the any type.
>
> ```
> import x, {y} from "hot-new-module";
> x(y);
> ```

right now I have the following, but it's not correct:

*./src/app/shared/my-marker-clusterer.d.ts*

```
/// <reference path="/node_modules/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js" />
// ERROR: typescript says *.js is an unsupported extension

declare module "js-marker-clusterer" {
  export class MarkerClusterer {
    constructor(map: any, opt_markers?: any, opt_options?: any);
    map_: any;
    markers_: any[];
    clusters_: any[];
    ready_: boolean;
    addMarkers(markers: any[], opt_nodraw: boolean) : void;
  }
}
```

*/src/app/shared/my-marker-clusterer.ts*

```
/// <reference path="./my-marker-clusterer.d.ts" />
import { MarkerClusterer } from 'js-marker-clusterer';

declare var google;

export class MyMarkerClusterer extends MarkerClusterer {
  constructor(map: any, opt_markers?: any, opt_options?: any) {
    super(map, opt_markers, opt_options);
  }

  addMarkers(markers, opt_nodraw) {
    super.addMarkers(markers, opt_nodraw)
    this.triggerClustersChanged()
  }
  triggerClustersChanged(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(this.map_, 'clustersChanged', this.clusters_);
  }
}
```

I'm using `rollupjs` so `es2015` modules preferred

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll be darned, the code I posted above actually worked. I got the TS TS6054 error below, but it still worked.

```
1 /// <reference path="/node_modules/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js" />
src/app/shared/my-marker-clusterer.d.ts(1,1): error TS6054: File '/node_modules/js-marker-clusterer/src/markerclusterer.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.
```

I did have to manually edit the JS file and `export`:

```
export function MarkerClusterer(map, opt_markers, opt_options) {
   // ...
}
```

Is there a way I can do the same without editing the original JS file?